AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'inference_server_address' in Python script
Hello Stack Overflow community,
I am encountering an error while trying to run the 'lighteval' framework to evaluate "meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf" on the "GSM8K" dataset.
I use accelarate as an entry point (run_evals_accelerate.py). This is the relevant part of the code, that gives me the error:
--model_args "meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf" \
--model_dtype "torch.float16" \
--tasks "lighteval|gsm8k|0|0" \
--override_batch_size 1 \
--output_dir '/content/drive/MyDrive/thesis'

I'm following the instructions from the huggingface\lighteval repository step by step.
The error I get is this: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/lighteval/run_evals_accelerate.py", line 82, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/lighteval/logging/hierarchical_logger.py", line 166, in wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/lighteval/main_accelerate.py", line 73, in main
    model_config = create_model_config(args=args, accelerator=accelerator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/lighteval/models/model_config.py", line 273, in create_model_config
    if args.inference_server_address is not None and args.model_args is not None:
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'inference_server_address'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/accelerate", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/accelerate/commands/accelerate_cli.py", line 46, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/accelerate/commands/launch.py", line 1075, in launch_command
    simple_launcher(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/accelerate/commands/launch.py", line 681, in simple_launcher
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(returncode=process.returncode, cmd=cmd)

I have checked the relevant code around line 73 in main_accelerate.py, but I'm not sure how to address this issue. Has anybody encountered a similar problem or has ideas on what might be causing it? I would be grateful for your input.
Thank you in advance for your help!
